# Deep-Linking detect source

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have a question about deep-linking of Android: `Do we have any ways to detect source when open our app by deep-link?`. Example: When I search app in Google Chrome and then I open app by click on one of search result. Then we would have a params such as: `source = "google-chrome" or source = "com.android.chrome"`.

I research about that but I didn't found any solution for that. Thanks for your help !!

Answer (score 0):

activity.getReferrer().getAuthority